# Решение системы нелинейных уравнений Matlab

Tags: matlab, система-уравнений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решал систему уравнений встроенным методом, однако получил в итоге только одну точку, вместо трех. Как найти остальные?

функция

```
function F= root2d(x)
F(1) = 0.5*(-17.76*x(1)-103.79*x(1)^2+229.62*x(1)^3-226.31*x(1)^4+83.72*x(1)^5)+x(2);
F(2) = 0.2*(-x(1)-1.5*x(2)+1.2);
end
```

и сам скрипт

```
fun = @root2d;
x0 = [0,0];
x = fsolve(fun,x0)
```

Comment: а где временное приращение?

Comment: На экспоненте спросите, там есть профильный форум.

Answer (score 0):

Говорится, что эта функция не приспособлена для нахождения нескольких решений, судя по [этому](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15082-multiple-solutions-using-fsolve#answer_20481) ответу.

Но попадались такие описания (возможно более старые версии) с параметром `maxsols`, но сейчас такого параметра `options` просто нет.
[image: старая функция с параметром кол-ва решений]